# My TP-Link TG-3269 I not been recognized on Ubuntu 18 and 16

Tags: networking, wired, adapter, tp-link

I'm having a problem with my Wired Network Adapter in Ubuntu 18 and 16. The card is just not recognized, my OnBoard Network doesn't work anymore, so I bought a pci card TP-Link TG-3269, and it works well on Windows, but today I installed the Ubuntu and right after the system initialization the leds of the card get off and the system don't recognize it.
Heres the lspci output:

```
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Host Bridge (rev a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2)
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:07.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

As you are seen, there is not TP-Link adapter, just the Realtek that is the burned OnBoard card.

I really want to learn Ubuntu, but VM's sucks on old processors like mine.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it!**

Today I was trying again to make my Wired Network turn on on Ubuntu, so I just take off the yellow cable of the network, and put again, so I realized that the LEDs of the card turn on again and the system recognize it, but just for one second,so I open the network options and let it on screen to see whats happening, so I take the cable off and put again and still connected until now! \o/

Here's the magic:

[image]

I really don't know what happens, but just works, I think that this post will not help another peoples to fix their problems, but I will let this post on...